# Hibernate failed to lazily initialize a collection

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, jpa, persistence, mariadb-10.3

I set up two datasources in Spring Boot. In a controller I want to persist a couple of parent-child entities on both. They're almost identical bidirectional relationships, but the first one works, while the second emits a committing message but doesn't actually persist the child entity.
Entities from working datasource

```
@Entity
public class Brand {

private Integer id;

private Set<Line> lines = new HashSet<Line>(); 

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
@JsonIgnore
public Integer getId() {
    return id;
}

@JsonIgnore
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "brand", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
public Set<Line> getLines() {
    return lines;
}
```

---

```
@Entity
public class Line {

private Integer id;

private Brand brand;

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
public Integer getId() {
    return id;
}

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "brand")
public Brand getBrand() {
    return brand;
}
```

while this ones are from second datasource, that persists the parent but not the child

```
@Entity
public class User {

private String id;

private List<UserCommit> userCommitList = new ArrayList<UserCommit>();

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
public Integer getId() {
    return id;
}
}

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "user", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
public List<UserCommit> getUserCommitList() {
    return userCommitList;
}
```

---

```
@Entity
public class UserCommit {

private Integer id;

private User user;

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
public Integer getId() {
    return id;
}

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "user")
public User getUser() {
    return user;
}
```

This is the the interesting part of the controller

```
    Brand brand = brandService.createFrom(fsDto.getBrand());
    Line line = lineService.createFrom(fsDto.getLine(), brand);
    AccessToken accToken = token.getAccount().getKeycloakSecurityContext().getToken();

    try {

        prodService.updateFrom(id, line, fsDto);

        User user = userService.createFrom(accToken);
        ucService.createFrom(user, id, "EDIT", "FIRST");
```

And these are the service methods

```
public Brand createFrom(String name) {

    Brand foundBrand = findByName(name);
    Brand brand = new Brand();
    if (foundBrand == null) {
        brand = brandRepo.save(brand);
        brand.setName(name);
    } else
        brand = foundBrand;

    return brand;
```

---

```
public Line createFrom(String name, Brand brand) {

    Line foundLine = findByNameAndBrand(name, brand);
    Line line = new Line();
    if (foundLine == null) {
        line.setName(name);
        line.setBrand(brand);
        line.getBrand().addLine(line);

    } else
        line = foundLine;

    return line;
}
```

---

```
public User createFrom(AccessToken accToken) {

    User user = findByKcId(accToken.getSubject());

    if(user == null) {
        user = new User();
        user.setKcId(accToken.getSubject());
        user.setName(accToken.getPreferredUsername());
        userRepo.save(user);
    }

    return user;

}
```

---

```
public UserCommit createFrom(User user, Integer prodId, String ucType, String stage) {

    UserCommit uc = new UserCommit();
    uc.setUser(user);
    uc.getUser().addUserCommit(uc);
    uc.setProdId(prodId);
    uc.setUCType(UserCommit.UCType.valueOf(ucType));
    uc.setStage(UserCommit.Stage.valueOf(stage));
    uc.setTime(LocalDateTime.now());

    return uc;
}
```

- Brand gets persisted.
- Line gets Persisted.
- User gets persisted.
- UserCommit DON'T get persisted.
- Everything works if I explicitly
  call UserCommitService.save(), but I think it shouldn't be needed.

**EDIT**
I updated my code to make the two couples of transactions even more similar, and now for the second one I got this classic error on lazy initialization.

```
org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: failed to lazily initialize a collection of role: petmenu.entities.users.User.userCommitList, could not initialize proxy - no Session
```

What really drives me mad, is that Brand→Line works, while User→UserCommit doesn't. Even tracing JPA I cannot understand why User entity is not included in the session at UserCommit commiting.

```
2020-05-26 16:51:54.258 DEBUG 78269 --- [http-nio-192.168.1.10-8080-exec-2] o.s.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager        : Found thread-bound EntityManager [SessionImpl(1767213597<open>)] for JPA transaction
2020-05-26 16:51:54.258 DEBUG 78269 --- [http-nio-192.168.1.10-8080-exec-2] o.s.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager        : Creating new transaction with name [petmenu.services.users.UserService.createFrom]: PROPAGATION_REQUIRED,ISOLATION_DEFAULT
2020-05-26 16:51:54.259 DEBUG 78269 --- [http-nio-192.168.1.10-8080-exec-2] o.s.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager        : Exposing JPA transaction as JDBC [org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect$HibernateConnectionHandle@41ca5759]
2020-05-26 16:52:01.687 DEBUG 78269 --- [http-nio-192.168.1.10-8080-exec-2] o.s.orm.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryUtils    : Opening JPA EntityManager
2020-05-26 16:52:01.708 DEBUG 78269 --- [http-nio-192.168.1.10-8080-exec-2] org.hibernate.SQL                        : select user0_.id as id1_0_, user0_.kc_id as kc_id2_0_, user0_.name as name3_0_ from user user0_ where user0_.kc_id=?
2020-05-26 16:52:01.708 TRACE 78269 --- [http-nio-192.168.1.10-8080-exec-2] o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder      : binding parameter [1] as [VARCHAR] - [80a3b4b1-00d1-4062-a7e5-1927b938c203]
2020-05-26 16:52:01.709 TRACE 78269 --- [http-nio-192.168.1.10-8080-exec-2] o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicExtractor   : extracted value ([id1_0_] : [INTEGER]) - [2005]
2020-05-26 16:52:01.709 TRACE 78269 --- [http-nio-192.168.1.10-8080-exec-2] o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicExtractor   : extracted value ([kc_id2_0_] : [VARCHAR]) - [80a3b4b1-00d1-4062-a7e5-1927b938c203]
2020-05-26 16:52:01.709 TRACE 78269 --- [http-nio-192.168.1.10-8080-exec-2] o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicExtractor   : extracted value ([name3_0_] : [VARCHAR]) - [user1]
2020-05-26 16:52:01.709 TRACE 78269 --- [http-nio-192.168.1.10-8080-exec-2] o.s.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager        : Triggering beforeCommit synchronization
2020-05-26 16:52:01.709 TRACE 78269 --- [http-nio-192.168.1.10-8080-exec-2] o.s.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager        : Triggering beforeCompletion synchronization
2020-05-26 16:52:01.709 DEBUG 78269 --- [http-nio-192.168.1.10-8080-exec-2] o.s.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager        : Initiating transaction commit
2020-05-26 16:52:01.709 DEBUG 78269 --- [http-nio-192.168.1.10-8080-exec-2] o.s.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager        : Committing JPA transaction on EntityManager [SessionImpl(1767213597<open>)]
2020-05-26 16:53:06.630 TRACE 78269 --- [http-nio-192.168.1.10-8080-exec-2] o.s.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager        : Triggering afterCommit synchronization
2020-05-26 16:53:06.671 TRACE 78269 --- [http-nio-192.168.1.10-8080-exec-2] o.s.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager        : Triggering afterCompletion synchronization
2020-05-26 16:53:06.671 DEBUG 78269 --- [http-nio-192.168.1.10-8080-exec-2] o.s.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager        : Not closing pre-bound JPA EntityManager after transaction
2020-05-26 16:53:06.671 DEBUG 78269 --- [http-nio-192.168.1.10-8080-exec-2] o.s.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager        : Found thread-bound EntityManager [SessionImpl(1767213597<open>)] for JPA transaction
2020-05-26 16:53:06.671 DEBUG 78269 --- [http-nio-192.168.1.10-8080-exec-2] o.s.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager        : Creating new transaction with name [petmenu.services.users.UserCommitService.createFrom]: PROPAGATION_REQUIRED,ISOLATION_DEFAULT
2020-05-26 16:53:06.671 DEBUG 78269 --- [http-nio-192.168.1.10-8080-exec-2] o.s.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager        : Exposing JPA transaction as JDBC [org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect$HibernateConnectionHandle@323b85aa]
2020-05-26 16:53:17.438 TRACE 78269 --- [http-nio-192.168.1.10-8080-exec-2] o.s.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager        : Triggering beforeCompletion synchronization
2020-05-26 16:53:17.472 DEBUG 78269 --- [http-nio-192.168.1.10-8080-exec-2] o.s.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager        : Initiating transaction rollback
2020-05-26 16:53:17.472 DEBUG 78269 --- [http-nio-192.168.1.10-8080-exec-2] o.s.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager        : Rolling back JPA transaction on EntityManager [SessionImpl(1767213597<open>)]
2020-05-26 16:53:17.472 TRACE 78269 --- [http-nio-192.168.1.10-8080-exec-2] o.s.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager        : Triggering afterCompletion synchronization
2020-05-26 16:53:17.472 DEBUG 78269 --- [http-nio-192.168.1.10-8080-exec-2] o.s.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager        : Not closing pre-bound JPA EntityManager after transaction
2020-05-26 16:53:17.473 DEBUG 78269 --- [http-nio-192.168.1.10-8080-exec-2] o.j.s.OpenEntityManagerInViewInterceptor : Closing JPA EntityManager in OpenEntityManagerInViewInterceptor
2020-05-26 16:53:17.496 ERROR 78269 --- [http-nio-192.168.1.10-8080-exec-2] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: failed to lazily initialize a collection of role: petmenu.entities.users.User.userCommitList, could not initialize proxy - no Session] with root cause
```

Comment: Never worked with Entity but it looks like your saving the user than adding the commit.
User createFrom(AccessToken accToken)  -->saves the user
UserCommit createFrom -->  creates the usercommit 
Have you tried adding the commit then saving the user a second time just to see if that's the case?

Comment: Yes. I do the same thing with Brand and Line  and it works.

Answer (score 0):

I studied a lot of stuff about transaction management etc. and I (hopefully) find the culprit. 
**But every correction is thankfully accepted**.

**LSS**

It seems that Spring Boot registers `OpenEntityManagerInViewInterceptor` just for the primary datasource (I find some info about this on the net, but nothing on official docs).

**TL:DR**

Bounding a session to the whole view and loading eagerly managed entities' collections, when running `LineService.createFrom` Brand's collection is already persisted, then the newly added Line gets flushed at the end of the transaction.
On the counterpart without the view-session, I got no managed collection inside `UserCommitService.createFrom` transaction, then without an explicit call to `UserCommitRepo.save` the UserCommit will remain transient and will be silently discarded from flushing at transaction commit.

I don't know if I understood everything correctly, and if that's the case, I'd like somebody to explain what's the point in `CascadeType.PERSIST` (included in `CascadeType.ALL`) on a `@OneToMany` side of a bidirectional
relationship.